# when a text is entered into textbox the value of dropdown menu should change

Tags: jquery, html, css

[Jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/9bRXd/13/)

Hello,
I am giving an example.Lets say we have two states in which there are two to three cities and when I type a city name into the textbox the State should be automatically selected fro, drop down list.
I am new to jquery.Please help me.

```
<div>City<span class="red">*</span> 
<input type="text" placeholder="City" id="city" name="city" required/>
</div>
<div>State<span class="red">*</span> 
<select name="state" id="state">
    <option id="st1" value="st1">State1</option>
    <option id="st2" value="st2">State2</option>
    <option id="st3" value="st3">State3</option>
    <option id="st4" value="st4">State4</option>
</select>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {

if ($("#city").val() == citya || $("city").val() == cityb || $("city").val() == cityc) {
    alert("State1");
} else if ($("#city").val() == cityd || $("city").val() == citye || $("city").val() == cityf) {
    $("#state").keyup("st2");
} else if ($("#city").val() == cityg || $("city").val() == cityh || $("city").val() == cityi) {
    $("#state").keyup("st3");
} else if ($("#city").val() == cityj || $("city").val() == cityk || $("city").val() == cityl) {
    $("#state").keyup("st4");
}

});
```

Comment: Where is citya to cityl is come from? Is these are variables, or clear text? If clear text, then add a quote or double quote around them like `'citya'` And use `$("#state").val("st4");` instead `$("#state").keyup("st4");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

You need to check your `#city` on key up. So when i entered a text, the if i entered `citya` it will `alert("State1");` Use `$(this)` when you attach a function to an element, to access that element. Also, `===` is better then `==`. Search the net for the operators for javascript.

```
    $('#city').keyup(function() {
        if ($(this).val() === 'citya' || $(this).val() === 'cityb' || $(this).val() === 'cityc') {
            alert("State1");
        } else if ($(this).val() === 'cityd' || $(this).val() === 'citye' || $(this).val() === 'cityf') {
            $("#state").val("st2");
        } else if ($(this).val() === 'cityg' || $(this).val() === 'cityh' || $(this).val() === 'cityi') {
            $("#state").val("st3");
        } else if ($(this).val() === 'cityj' || $(this).val() === 'cityk' || $(this).val() === 'cityl') {
            $("#state").val("st4");
        }
    });
```

Here is a working jsfiddle **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lfzf37um/)**